# How to position a div under an other div that has a float:right

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a menu div with a `float:right` (which I cant change because its as default in all my WP pages).

I want to add a div that will stick to the right, under the menu div.

I made a little paint work to show you: 
[image]

- The black part is a div.
- The nav menu on the top right.
- The yellow div is the part that I'm trying to get to.

I tried using `absolute` positioning for it, But it's kind of a problem since the page has to be responsive.

I tried using `vertically-align`, it worked with positioning the div, but when I gave the yellow div `width:50%` it pushed the menu to the middle of the page as if it took it's place.

How can I position the yellow div with the texts?

This is what I have to build: 
[image]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z933zvev/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="careers">

    <div class="top">
        <ul> <!-- First Menu -->
            <li> <a href="#"> Clients </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> About Us </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
            <li class="hasImage"> <a href="#"> <img src="<?php echo $themedir;?>/images/yellow_logo_top_menu_yellow.png" class="logo"> </a> </li>
        </ul> <!-- End First Menu -->

        <div class="top-texts">
            <div><h1 class="text-yellow">texttexttexttexttexttext.</h1></div>
            <div><h2>Together.</h2></div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="<?php echo $themedir;?>/images/open positions.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="texts">

        </div>




    </div>

</div> <!-- END main -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear#Syntax) property, to use your red & yellow example:

```
.red { 
    float:right; color:red; border: solid 5px; padding: 5px; 
}
.yellow { 
    float:right; color:yellow; border: solid 5px; padding: 5px; 
    clear:right; /* use clear property */
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/z933zvev/2/

Answer (score 1):

First off, your html is broken in your fiddle.  It looks correct in your post though.  All you have to do is float your top-texts div right and set clear: both so it floats on its own line.

```
.top-texts {
clear: both;
float:right;
}
```

Fiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/psnue6fg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of doing it with `clear:right` *and* your actual code.

Just add this class to your `CSS`

```
.top-texts{   
    text-align: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-right: 35px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z933zvev/4/)

Hope it helps.